# Implementing jobshop problem in old ORTools

Tags: c++, constraint-programming, or-tools

I want to implement this simple jobshop example: https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop
but in the old version of ORTools in C++ and I can't seem to find any support for the syntaxes in the older version. I have to write it in the old version to learn the syntaxes cause I have a bigger code that's written in the older version that I have to work on and I was hoping I could find an example that's written in the old version of ORTools to learn.
For example: a declaration of the solver in the new version:
`_modelBuilder = new sat::CpModelBuilder();`

and a declaration of the solver in the older version

`_modelBuilder = new Solver("scheduler", parameters);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old version can be found in earlier releases:

see [here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/6.7.x/examples/cpp/jobshop.cc).

This being said

- it is no longer developed
- the CP-SAT version is much better.

Comment: Thank you. Also, why does everyone say the CP-SAT version is better exactly?

Comment: It is not the same technology. Read 'search is dead' from Peter Stucker, or watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmy1ddn4cyw